# Create a stacked bar chart of the N largest columns per row in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe of **N** columns of values by **M** dates.

I'm looking to plot a stacked bar chart of the 3 largest values per date.

**Test dataframe:**

```
import pandas
import numpy

data = {
    'A': [ 65, 54, 12, 14, 30, numpy.nan ],
    'B': [ 54, 47, 60, 34, 40, 35 ],
    'C': [ 34, 39, 57, 56, 48, numpy.nan ],
    'D': [ 20, 18, 47, 47, 35, 70 ]
}

df = pandas.DataFrame(index=pandas.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-01-06').date,
                      data=data,
                      dtype=numpy.float64)
```

> ```
>                A     B     C     D
> 2018-01-01  65.0  54.0  34.0  20.0
> 2018-01-02  54.0  47.0  39.0  18.0
> 2018-01-03  12.0  60.0  57.0  47.0
> 2018-01-04  14.0  34.0  56.0  47.0
> 2018-01-05  30.0  40.0  48.0  35.0
> 2018-01-06   NaN  35.0   NaN  70.0
> ```

**Extracting the 3 largest values per row:**

I have found [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) which I can use to extract the 3 largest columns and their respective values for each row:

```
for date,row in df.iterrows():
    top = row.nlargest(3)
    s = [f'{c}={v}' for c,v in top.iteritems()]
    print('{}: [ {} ]'.format(date, ', '.join(s)))
```

> ```
> 2018-01-01: [ A=65.0, B=54.0, C=34.0 ]
> 2018-01-02: [ A=54.0, B=47.0, C=39.0 ]
> 2018-01-03: [ B=60.0, C=57.0, D=47.0 ]
> 2018-01-04: [ C=56.0, D=47.0, B=34.0 ]
> 2018-01-05: [ C=48.0, B=40.0, D=35.0 ]
> 2018-01-06: [ D=70.0, B=35.0 ]
> ```

**Plotting the data in a stacked bar chart:**

The final step, to take the above data and plot a stacked bar chart so that it looks like the example below, I have been unsuccessful in.

I'm not even sure if `nlargest` is the best approach.

**Desired output:**

[image: stacked barchart example]

**Question:**

How can I create a stacked bar chart of the N largest columns per row in a dataframe?

Comment: this seems to provide what you are looking for: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html

Answer (score 5):

Starting with your input `df`:

```
top3_by_date = (
    # bring the date back as a column to use as a grouping var
    df.reset_index()
    # make a long DF of date/column/name value
    .melt(id_vars='index')
    # order DF by highest values first
    .sort_values('value', ascending=False)
    # group by the index and take the first 3 rows of each
    .groupby('index')
    .head(3)
    # pivot back so we've got an X & Y to chart...
    .pivot('index', 'variable')
    # drop the value level as we don't need that
    .droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
)
```

This gives:

```
variable       A     B     C     D
index                             
2018-01-01  65.0  54.0  34.0   NaN
2018-01-02  54.0  47.0  39.0   NaN
2018-01-03   NaN  60.0  57.0  47.0
2018-01-04   NaN  34.0  56.0  47.0
2018-01-05   NaN  40.0  48.0  35.0
2018-01-06   NaN  35.0   NaN  70.0
```

Then you can do `top3_by_date.plot.bar(stacked=True)`, which should give you something similar to:

[image]

Comment: Wow - I am equal parts impressed and terrified by that melting/grouping/pivoting magic you did there!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but somewhat convoluted, since you need to use [`bottom`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) to offset each bar above those at the same date with lower values. This prevents bars with higher values hiding bars with lower values.

For each column (representing one series in the bar chart), 3 arrays are required:

- **`dates`:** the dates which have values for this column (ie: the dates for which this column is one of the 3 largest values)
- **`values`**: the difference between this value and the next lower value
- **`bottoms`**: the value of the next lower value

**Building up the arrays:**

```
col_dates   = collections.defaultdict(list)
col_values  = collections.defaultdict(list)
col_bottoms = collections.defaultdict(list)

for date,row in df.iterrows():
    top = row.nlargest(3)
    for i,kv in enumerate(top.iteritems()):
        col, val = kv
        next_val = top.values[i+1] if i+1 < len(top.values) else 0

        col_dates  [col].append(date)
        col_values [col].append(val - next_val)
        col_bottoms[col].append(next_val)
```

**Plotting the bar chart:**

```
fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

for col,vals in col_values.items():
    dates   = col_dates[col]
    bottoms = col_bottoms[col]

    ax.bar(matplotlib.dates.date2num(dates), vals, width=.6, bottom=bottoms, label=col)
    ax.xaxis_date()

ax.legend(loc='best', fontsize='large')

pyplot.show()
```

**The resulting plot:**

[image]

Comment: Ahh... so you also wanted to order the stacking?

Comment: @JonClements I want the y-axis to be the same as the values in the dataframe, rather than the sum of the values which is what yours does. Is that what you referred to by "ordering" the stacking?

Comment: Yes... sorry - it wasn't clear in your Q what difficulty you were having - I read (incorrectly) it as difficulty in conveniently manipulating the DF without using iterrows and defaultdicts and all that stuff...

Comment: In all honesty it was both! The code I came up with is not efficient at all!

Comment: Gotta go do stuff right now - but I might have a chance later to look again.

Comment: @JonClements thanks, from an intellectual curiosity perspective I'd appreciate your insight... although what I have is working for me, so I'm making forward progress! :)

Comment: Would you mind making an edit to your Q such that you make it clear how you want the ordering of the stacking to work? I'm far from a pandas/matplotlib expert but I know many are... and I got confused on what you were asking here so others may do so also... but it'd be really good to see this one solved cleanly without resorting to `iterrows` (or even without melting and grouping - some people here can do some extraordinary stuff that blows my mind) etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple `apply`. It will not be vectorized but I think it's much clearer to read. In this case I filled `NaN` with `-np.inf` because sort doesn't work well with `NaN` values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'A': [ 65, 54, 12, 14, 30, np.nan ],
    'B': [ 54, 47, 60, 34, 40, 35 ],
    'C': [ 34, 39, 57, 56, 48, np.nan ],
    'D': [ 20, 18, 47, 47, 35, 70 ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-01-06').date,
                  data=data,
                  dtype=np.float64)

df.fillna(-np.inf, inplace=True)

def search_rows(row):
    return np.where(row.isin(sorted(row, reverse=True)[:3]), row, -np.inf)

df = df.apply(search_rows, axis=1)
df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```