# How to create a stacked bar chart showing only Top N rows (values) per column

Tags: python, stacked-chart, top-n

I'm new to Python, and working on this project looking at deals won by an IT company.
For the data below I'd like to create a  **stacked bar chart that shows only the top 5 'VP-Manager' values per 'Client Category'** i.e. the top 5 'VP-Manager' who have won the most deals per 'Client Category'.

[Data Sample][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9sdG.png

I took guidance from @Jon Clements response on the below question:
[Create a stacked bar chart of the N largest columns per row in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361624/create-a-stacked-bar-chart-of-the-n-largest-columns-per-row-in-a-dataframe)

This was my code:

```
top5 = (
    # bring the client category back as a column to use as a grouping var
    dataw.reset_index()
    # make a long DF of client category/column/name value
    .melt(id_vars='Client Category')
    # order DF by highest values first
    .sort_values('VP-Manager', ascending=False)
    # group by the index and take the first 5 rows of each
    .groupby('Client Category')
    .head(5)
    # pivot back so we've got an X & Y to chart...
    .pivot('Client Category', 'VP-Manager')
    # drop the value level as we don't need that
    .droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
)

top5.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

But I keep getting an error
KeyError: 'VP-Manager'

Tried various things (and a couple other methods) but can't seem to fix this.

Please can someone help? Thank you!

Update: I'm looking for a chart similar to this -
[Desired Output][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb6Xl.jpg

Comment: The 'VP-Manager' column doesn't exist in the sort, which needs to be fixed at the time of melt.

Comment: @r-beginners Thanks, please can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: try this:`melt(id_vars='Client Category',var_vars='VP-Manager',...)`

Comment: Alternatively, stop sorting and the error will disappear.

Comment: @r-beginners Thank you, but the above didn't work. Adding  'VP-Manager' to the 'value' argument like below throws the same error. Removing the 'sort' gives a new error: "KeyError: "None of ['VP-Manager'] are in the columns"" `.melt(id_vars='Client Category', value_vars='VP-Manager')`

Comment: If you assume that the client category is not unique, the following code will work. `(pd.melt(dataw, id_vars=['Client Category', 'VP-Manager'], value_vars=['Deal Cost']).sort_values('VP-Manager', ascending=False) .groupby('Client Category') .head(5).pivot(index='Client Category', columns='VP-Manager').droplevel(level=0, axis=1))`

Comment: @r-beginners Thank you so much! It's been almost a week trying to find a solution to this. While I'm still not getting the result/chart I wanted (need top 5 VP-Manager based on number of records/wins, but getting something else), I'm just glad that the problem on the melt is now sorted - thanks again! Note - I had to change `pivot` to `pivot_table` as the former was throwing an error: "Value error: index contains duplicate entries cannot reshape"